# Is it possible to disable Spring Boot's autoexception handling from application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties, exception

**Is it possible to disable Spring Boot's autoexception handling from application.properties?**

I am trying to disable Spring Boots general exception handling without renaming error.html while coding and turn it on at production from application.properties.

I've found the following from Spring documentation:

> At start-up, Spring Boot tries to find a mapping for /error. By
>   convention, a URL ending in /error maps to a logical view of the same
>   name: error. In the demo application this view maps in turn to the
>   error.html Thymeleaf template. (If using JSP, it would map to
>   error.jsp according to the setup of your
>   InternalResourceViewResolver).
>
> If no mapping from /error to a View can be found, Spring Boot defines
>   its own fall-back error page - the so-called “Whitelabel Error Page”
>   (a minimal page with just the HTTP status information and any error
>   details, such as the message from an uncaught exception). If you
>   rename the error.html template to, say, error2.html then restart, you
>   will see it being used.

And also I tried the following properties which didn't work:

```
server.error.path=/somewrongurl
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
```

Answer (score -1):

Add following lines into your application.properties file

```
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
spring.resources.add-mappings=false
```

And define your own Exception Controller to catch all related exceptions like

```
    @ControllerAdvice
    public class ExceptionController {

         @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
         public ResponseEntity<?> handleException(Exception e) {
             //handle your exception
         }
    }
```